# jenkins behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, jenkins, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to keep a jenkins container(docker) behind nginx reverse proxy. It works fine with this path, https://example.com/ but it returns 502 Bad Gateway when I add parameter to the path, https://example.com/jenkins.

The docker container for jenkins is run like this
docker container run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins

Here is my code,

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;

        server_name schoolcloudy.com www.schoolcloudy.com;

        location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }

}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
upstream jenkins {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins;
    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins;
        proxy_redirect  127.0.0.1:8080 https://schoolcloudy.com/jenkins;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the Jenkins container's network with `--network=host` flag when you run the container. This way the container will be able to interact with host network or use the container's IP explicitly in the Nginx conf.

Answer (score 0):

good practice in such questions is official documentation usage:
[wiki.jenkins.io](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+nginx+reverse+proxy)
I've configured Jenkins behind Nginx reverse proxy several time, wiki works fine for me each time.

P.S.: look like `proxy_pass` option value in your config should be changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`